# Tensorflow: Increasing number of duplicate predictions while training

Tags: tensorflow

I have a multilayer perceptron with 5 hidden layers and 256 neurons each. When I start training, I get different prediction probabilities for each train sample until epoch 50, but then the number of duplicate predictions increases, on epoch 300 I already have 30% of duplicate predictions which does not make sense since the input data is different for all training samples. Any idea what causes this behavior?

**Clarifications:**

with "duplicate predictions", I mean items with the exactly same predicted probability to belong to class A (it's a binary classification problem)

I have 4000 training samples with 200 features each and all samples are different, it does not make sense that the number of duplicate predictions increases to 30% while training. So I wonder what can cause this behavior.

Comment: Can be many things. Your NN for example can learn a constant. Please show the code and preferably the data as well.

Comment: What u mean by the duplicate prediction?

Comment: Tom, you should edit your question to refine it, not add answers. Adding answers like this now marks your question as answered and reduces the likelyhood anyone will see it. I've moved the text of those answers into the question for you, I've flagged them as not answers so your question gets the appropriate attention.

Comment: @TomDriftwood so you are doing binary classification. What is the label distribution in your training data?

Answer (score 0):

One point, you say you are doing a binary prediction, and when you say "duplicate predictions", even with your clarification it's hard to understand your meaning. I am guessing that you have two outputs for your binary classifier, one for class A and one for class B and you are getting roughly the same value for a given sample. If that's the case, then the first thing to do is to use 1 output. A binary classification problem is better modeled with 1 output that ranges between 0 and 1 (sigmoid the output neuron). This way there will be no ambiguity, the network will have to choose one or the other, or when it's confused you'll get ~0.5 and it will be clear.

Second, it is very common for a network to start learning well and then to perform more poorly after overtraining. Especially with small datasets such as what you have. In fact, even with the little knowledge I have of your dataset I would put a small bet on you getting better performance out of an algorithm like XGA Boost than a neural network (I assume you're using a neural net and not literally a perceptron).

But regarding the performance degrading over time. When this happens you want to look into something called "early stopping". At some point the network will start memorizing the input, and may be part of what's happening. Essentially you train until the performance on your held out test data starts to worsen.

To address this you can apply various forms of regularization (L2 regularization, dropout, batch normalization all come to mind). You can also reduce the size of your network. 5 layers of 256 neurons sounds too big for the problem. Try trimming this down and I bet your results will improve. There is a sweet spot for architecture size in neural networks. When your network is too large it can, and often will, over fit. When it's too small it won't be expressive enough for the data. Angrew Ng's coursera class has some helpful practical advice on dealing with this.